# Data Extraction from images using NLP and ML

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, data-cleaning

[image]Hi i'm trying to extract data like name, planType, phone#, .. from images like insurance cards or licence cards with GoogleVision / Textract using some conditions  but it does not extract the correct content .

is there a way to use ML and NLP together to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: Please read your question again: we can't understand anything from it about your problem in practice. No one can help you at the moment

Comment: have a look at openCV

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform **OCR (Optical Character Recognition)**. 
However, this can lead to bad results if your images are of very bad quality, or they are skewed and distorted). 
One tool you can use is **tesseract** [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) from Google. You can train it for your purpose to recognize the text in your images.